# Create a Sequelize findAll where clause that returns all results regardless of punctuation in search string

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In a controller, using `findAll()`, I am trying to create a where clause to return all hits regardless of punctuation in the search string.  Currently, punctuation is dictating what is returned even though i'm using the `[Op.iLike]` operator.

Example:

`search` can either be `'St Andrew'` or `'St. Andrew'`

In the following example: if `search === 'St. Andrew'` returns only results with the `St. Andrew`
And, if `search === 'St Andrew'`, it only returns the results with `St Andrew`

```
where: { name: { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` } },
```

In the following example: if `search === 'St. Andrew'` returns all intended results (results with or without the `.`)
Howerver, if `search === 'St Andrew'`, it only returns the results without the `.`

```
const noPunctuationSearch = search?.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g, ' ');

where: {
  name: {
    [Op.or]: [
      { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` },
      { [Op.iLike]: `%${noPunctuationSearch}%` },
    ],
  },
},
```

How do I set up the where clause and Operators to return all `St. Andrew || St Andrew` results regardless of the punctuation in `search`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Op.iRegexp`](https://sequelize.org/v6/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators) but you will need to massage the query a bit more to create a regular expression out of it.

```js
const search = 'St. Andrews';

const noPuncuationSearch = search?.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g,'[^A-Za-z0-9]+');

where: {
  name: {
    [Op.iRegexp]: noPuncuationSearch,
  },
},
```

Comment: It's clever -- why does this solution work as a case insensitive query?

Comment: Because it is using a regular expression against the contents of your DB. Your original code was just using two different search strings and then trying to find one of them in the DB contents. If none matched nothing would be returned.